# How can I get a passwordless remote connection (OS authentication) to Oracle DB?

Tags: database, oracle, catalog

I'm considering using remote OS authentication to connect to an Oracle database (version 11g). What are the guidelines for using [`remote_os_authent`]

Here's what I want to do:
We set up a catalog DB  to used by RMAN to store metadata about Oracle databases.
I want to connect to the catalog DB via the local machine and execute this command for resync catalog db:

***rman target sys/pass@localdb;
connect catalog catuser/password@catdb;
RESYNC CATALOG;***

Is it possible for me to do this through oracle Enterprise Manager job?
(I did this process by calling the execute file, but the problem is that the passwords are clear in the executable file.)
I need it because I do not want user passwords to be available and visible.
I can't use oracle valet for passwordless connection.

Comment: You edited the question ..... and still, my answer is valid, you can use the wallet for the catalog connection. Yes, you can also use OEM to do the same and there also the password has to be maintained. I believe OEM has a special kind of job for this.

Comment: Hi ik_zelf . Yes, I edited my questions because I felt I had not conveyed what I intended.
Using Oracle wallet is a good solution, but the problem is that the server on which I want to create the job is out of my site and I can not control access to the server. So if someone has access to the server, they can connect directly to my database, and this will increase access security.

Comment: My whole effort is to be able to connect to my Oracle catalog database from my local database and execute the resync command, and I am looking for a solution that can execute the connection information and the directory resync command in a way using the database Job or procedure's .

Comment: if you setup your environment correctly: ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME, your local connect can be "/" and for your catalog just create a wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Using remote os authentication is considered a bad habit because it is insecure.

If you want to have scripting without having to store passwords in a readable format to prevent leaking passwords, easiest is to use the oracle wallet for this.
This still keeps you busy maintaining passwords in the database and in the wallet but it is pretty safe.
Your connection would be something line `sqlplus /@tns_alias`
where the tns_alias is the key into the wallet that fetches the username and the password.
An example of setup can be found here: http://ronr.blogspot.com/2017/01/cleartext-userid-and-passwords-in.html

An other option could be to enable Central Managed Users (CMU) and kerberos. This does need quite a bit of setup and is less suitable for scripting. For interactive use it works very nice, assuming you have kerberos correctly setup.
An example of CMU setup can be found here: https://blog.pythian.com/part-1-creating-an-oracle-18c-centrally-managed-users-testbed-using-oracle-cloud-infrastructure/

Please change back remote_os_authentication to false. It is not safe because users can easily be spoofed.